# A-GPS location from mobile internet stick

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, internet

I have Huawei E1550 connected to my RaspberryPi with Arch-Linux mounted in my car working with german vodafone. I wonder if I can get the A-GPS location from that internet-stick.

In times without smartphones and google and stuff it was already possible to get a rough location information through a-gps, in older times it has been also charged by the ISP.

**Is it technically and practically possible to get the A-GPS based location through an mobile internet stick with linux?**

Comment: What you’re talking about is not A-GPS. A-GPS is Assisted GPS. It still requires a GPS receiver and reception. You’re talking about is network-based positioning.

Comment: oh, correct. Is it possible to use this with a mobile internet stick?

Comment: The google location service could do it, but Im unsure if you can implement that outside of Android.